# Jquery ajax variables into php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi i'm trying to retrieve response after passing some variables from javascript to php using jquery ajax functions.

This is the jquery ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#invoice_submit_button").click(function() {

        var action = $("invoice_form").attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: $('form#invoice_form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.error == 'none') {
                    $("#ajax_response").html("<p>" + response.msg + "</p>");
                }
                else {

                    $("#ajax_response").html("<p>" + response.msg + "</p>");

                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

(ofc there will be different outputs depending on the response.error when get it to work, it's just an example)

This is the php code:

```
$msg="Bla bla";
$error="form_err";
$result = array('msg' => $msg, 'error' => $error);
$result_json = json_encode($result);
echo $result_json;
```

Debugging using firebug shows that there're not issues with the posting part but it looks like the script can't get a response from php(and print it into the target div).
I'm missing something, i used the same method for other scripts and it has always worked.
Thanks

Comment: `action` is empty as jQuery cannot find an element `invoice_form`. `$("invoice_form").attr('action');` should be `$("#invoice_form").attr('action');`. Are you sure the request is sent to the correct URL?

Comment: Great, thanks. I lost the # copy pasting from an old script.
edit: can't i rep or whatever comments?

Comment: I provided my comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` is empty as jQuery cannot find an element `invoice_form`.

`$("invoice_form").attr('action');` should be `$("#invoice_form").attr('action');`.

Are you sure the request is sent to the correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the content type to application/json in your PHP script?

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Will probably not make any difference.